# Excel sum column based on two other column criteria don't count duplicate or correponding original

Tags: excel, countif

I want to sum column c based on the text of "success" in column b while removing duplicates and originals in column a. For example:
a1=1, b1=success, a2=2, b2=success, a3=2, b3=success, a4=3, b4=success and a5=4 and b5=fail. So the total should be 4. I can have it not count the duplicates, but I don't want the original of the duplicate either.
Thanks

Comment: can you explain this better ? how do you get a total of 4 ?

Comment: I only want to sum the rows in column a if 1) column b= success and then 2) there is no duplicate row in column a. So if a1 = 1 and a2=1 then I don't want either a1 or a2 counted. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: not really, you mention sum, and also count, i am little confused, by sum the rows, do you mean count the rows or add up all the values in column A that match a value ?

Comment: I mean add up the values in column a that match a value of success in column b, while removing any duplicate and the corresponding original

Comment: ok i tihnk im getting there, so how do you define what the original is, and what is the duplicate ?

Comment: in your example to get a total of 4, are you summing A1 & A4 ?

Comment: I apologize. Let me start over. I am trying to sum the total $ amount of several transactions. Each transaction will have a receipt # in column a, a dollar amount in column b, and either 'success' or 'failure' in column c. I want the total dollars of all successful transactions HOWEVER, when a refund is given the receipt # is the same. So if I can have two rows that say success but one if a refund so I want the refund row and the corresponding original row both not counted in the total $ amount.

Answer (score 0):

Ok not 100% i understand but heres my best shot:

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,A1:A5)>1,0,A1:A5))-SUMIF(B1:B5,"fail",A1:A5)
```

enter it as an array formula using `Ctrl` + `Enter` + `Shift`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

With this **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together), you can achieve your goal:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:$B$5="Success"),--(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5,$A$1:$A$5)<2),$C$1:$C$5)
```

Comment: What if I want to total a value in column c, based on only non-duplicates of column a. For example, if column c has a value of 1 in every row, and the total would equal 2.

Comment: Just updated my answer.  Simply change the last `$A$1:$A$5` to `$C$1:$C$5`.

Comment: One more question. On my =SUMPRODUCT statement, how can I add to total if column b = "received" in addition to "success". I have tried several ways, and nothing is working.

Comment: Something like this: `($B$1:$B$5="Success")*($B$1:$B$5="received")`. This will work as `AND`. For `OR`, you can try: `($B$1:$B$5={"Success","received"})`. I don't have any PC around me to test but give it a shot first and let me know.